# Is it possible to inspect standard components?

Tags: debugging, qt

I am trying to get familiar with the QtCreator IDE. However, I've come to notice that while debugging, I can't take a closer look at the standard components. Looking at the included picture, I can't go deeper into, say the QString `name` property of temp in the locals and watches view on the right side of the screen. Let's say I want to know it's length while debugging. I can't see that now, as I don't get more information about the `name` property.

My question is rather simple. How can I inspect these standard components (as the `name` property is a QString) deeper, showing me detailed info about the QString itself and not only it's contents.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is solved by de-selecting the Debug Helper from the Debug options menu (Tools -> Options -> Debug -> Debug helper tab).

[image]